# Why current is constant during storage phase in reverse recovery experiment?

Tags: diodes, transient, pn-junction, lifetime

This is a simple schematic of reverse recovery experiment.
[image: reverse recovery experiment]

As you can see, there is a constant current phase in the curve known as storage phase. My question is, why 
current is constant during storage phase? I have read in references that during this phase, injected minority carriers (in forward bias) will recombine.
it's OK, but I could not find any convincing answer for my question in related references. I would appreciate if you could kindly help me.

Comment: The current in the storage phase is constant because Ur ard Rr are constant. Constant voltage and constant resistance gives constant current.

Answer (score 1):

> why current is constant during storage phase?

We assume the switch has been in the storage position for a long time before we started the experiment, allowing the diode to reach a steady state behavior with forward bias. The details of how it got there, and what transient behavior happened when the switch was first moved to the left, don't matter when it comes to understanding reverse recovery, so we don't make the plot more confusing by including those behaviors.

Answer (score 0):

The time scale intercept you show is steady state.

Below both transitions and equations are given, which may be a better illustration.

[image]